# Android-App crashes on startup where can i find device logs?

Tags: android

My app is crashing directly on startup of the app in Android 4.2. If I start it on 2.3 it works without errors.

What is the best practice to find out the reason of this crash? Where are the android device logs?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make it to the first breakpoint in your startup form? Check your manifest.

Comment: The command "adb logcat" will start displaying the log. Once that's active, start your app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse: go to Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat.

Besides that, I think if your app crashes on JB, but not on GB, then I would check for a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Edit:
You're performing a (potentially slow) network operation in your main UI thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.

You could use an AsyncTask to get around this, by loading the data in its doInBackground(..).

Comment: yes I have a NetworkOnMainThreadException, what is the reason for this?